# How to sort GitHub issues by the latest issues that contain at least one comment from me?

Tags: github, github-issues

I often find myself browsing through a GitHub Issues tracker and wanting to sort the results by the most recent issues that contain at least one comment from me.

What prompts should I use to be able to do this?